# Why doesn't TargetDataLine.read() throw any exception when the device is disconnected?

Tags: java, audio-recording, javasound

According to the docs, `TargetDataLine.read()` is a blocking method, i.e., calling to `read()` blocks until it has the requested number of bytes available to read. However, it returns immediately if the data line is closed, stopped, drained, or flushed.

I have a real time application that reads and processes data from an audio interface indefinitely. My audio device interfaces to the computer through an USB connection. If I unplug the USB connection while data is being read, my application blocks at the `read()` method indefinitely without throwing any exception. Is it an expected behaviour or there any way around to detect that physical connection has been removed?

**Update 1:** Bellow code snippet can reproduce the issue.

```
public class TestSoundCapture {

    public TestSoundCapture() {
        new Thread(new CaptureBack()).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSoundCapture();
    }

    private class CaptureBack implements Runnable {

        public CaptureBack() { }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] shortBuffer = new byte[2048];

            final TargetDataLine dataLine = getDataLine();
            dataLine.start();  // begin audio capture. 

            while (true) {
                try {
                    numBytesRead = dataLine.read(shortBuffer, 0, shortBuffer.length);
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Store "+numBytesRead+" in a circular buffer");
            }           

            // stop and close the line.
            dataLine.stop();
            dataLine.close();
            System.out.println("Capturing Finished!");
        } 

        private TargetDataLine getDataLine() {
            AudioFormat aFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);
            TargetDataLine line = null;
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, aFormat);

            try {
                line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                line.open(aFormat);
            } 
            catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            }  

            return line;
        }
    }
}
```

When the audio device is disconnected, background thread is stuck at the `read()` method.

**Update 2:** Even thought I don't like it, one possible work around could be checking `available()` before attempting to read. To be specific, call `read()` iff `available()` returns greater or equal amount of bytes that I would like to read.

```
int counter = 0;  // counts number of consecutive failed attempt.
final int buffSize = 2048;

while (true) {
     if (counter > 3) break;   // no data available on the line.

     Thread.sleep(20);

     if (dataLine.available() < buffSize) {
         counter++;
         continue;
     }
     else {
         numBytesRead = dataLine.read(shortBuffer, 0, buffSize);
         counter = 0;
     }                        

     System.out.println("Store "+numBytesRead+" in a circular buffer");
}
```

Comment: *"without throwing any exception"* The [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) method can only throw two exceptions: `IllegalArgumentException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Which of these did you envision it would throw?

Comment: None!
I was expecting `LineUnavailableException` exception, but unfortunately `read()` cannot throw it. Therefore, I am looking for a work around so that my application doesn't block at `read()` method indefinitely.

Comment: Are you sure the `read` method is blocking, and it's not just you that keeps calling it in a loop and it keeps returning `0`? I mean, the doc says *"if the data line is closed, stopped, drained, or flushed before the requested amount has been read, the method no longer blocks, but returns the number of bytes read thus far"*, so if the device is disconnected, I'd expect the line to be closed. Maybe you need to call `isOpen​()`?

Comment: I hoped so but unfortunately it didn't so!
No luck with `isOpen()/isRunning()` or `addLineListener()`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Added SSCCE @AndrewThompson